# python string find and replace in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm reading a file and replacing a text string. I'm doing this for a few different strings, I know this isn't the most effeciant code I'm just trying to get it working. Here's what I have:

```
    for line in fileinput.input(new_config, inplace=1):
        print line.replace("http://domain.com", self.site_address)
        print line.replace("dbname", self.db_name)
        print line.replace("root", self.db_user)
        print line.replace("password", self.db_pass)
        print line.replace("smvc_", self.prefix
```

this works but it also writes every line in the file 5 times and only replaces the string on the first attempt on not on the new lines it creates (doesn't matter if it matches the string or not)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to treat it as one string and apply all replacements to it.

```
for line in fileinput.input(new_config, inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("http://domain.com", self.site_address)
    line = line.replace("dbname", self.db_name)
    line = line.replace("root", self.db_user)
    line = line.replace("password", self.db_pass)
    line = line.replace("smvc_", self.prefix)
    print line
```

If it doesn't find any of those targets it will just not make any change to the `line` string so it will just replace what it DOES find.

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in fileinput.input(new_config, inplace=1):
    print line.replace(
        "http://domain.com", self.site_address).replace(
        "dbname", self.db_name).replace(
         "root", self.db_user).replace(
         "password", self.db_pass).replace("smvc_", self.prefix)
```

Done by copying and pasting what you wrote and using only the delete key and re-indenting. No characters added except the last closing paren.

Alternatively, this format may be clearer. It uses the backslash character to split the one line in a neater way, for better readability:

```
    print line.replace("http://domain.com", self.site_address) \
              .replace("dbname", self.db_name) \
              .replace("root", self.db_user) \
              .replace("password", self.db_pass) \
              .replace("smvc_", self.prefix)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read a file line by line. 
And at every line look for the word you would like to replace.

For example:

```
line1 = 'Hello World There'
def Dummy():
    lineA = line1.replace('H', 'A')
    lineB = lineA.replace('e', 'o')
    print(lineB)

Dummy()
```

Then wirte `lineB` to a file.

Comment: And again a downvote without a comment. -_- My example does what the topic starter is asking for, just on a different way.... What is wrong with that? *demotivating*

Comment: Your solution uses a redundant function. Dummy can only operate on `line1` so why bother putting it in a function in the first place? It's probably not worthwhile (in this particular case) to have different variables for each replacement either.

Comment: If you read the first lines you see it should be used by a function that reads in a file line by line.. While it is reading every line then do a replace. So `line1` replesents the current line from the file that is being read.